# Infinite Loop - Firebase real time database - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm developing an a Android Studio board game and I'm having an loop that iterates till the piece gets out of the game (the board have 25 boxes so when I get over 25 crash) and I don't know exactly why.

So in the onCreate I have this code:

```
        String gameName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nom_partida");

        DatabaseReference gamesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("games");
        Query gameQuery = gamesRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(gameName);

        //carregar taulell
        loadBoard(gameQuery, gamesRef);
        //carregar peces jugadors atotes les caselles invisibles
        loadPieces();
        //carregar peces de la casella iniciañ
        loadPiecesFirstBox();
        //assignar colors designats als jugadors
        loadPlayers(gameName);

        // Wait for the players to finish loading before continuing with onCreate
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
           public void run() { 

                //for (Player player : players) { //recorre els jugadors
                throw(gameName);

                //}


            }
        }, 2000); // Wait for 2 seconds (adjust this time as needed)

        DatabaseReference gameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("games/" + gameName);

        gameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //TODO: Per tots els usuaris actualitzar la posició, quan canvii alguna cosa del joc.
                //Prohibit actualitzar la BD en aquest punt.
                Game game = new Game();
                game.setName(gameName);
                game.setCurrentPlayerIndex(0);

                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                String playerId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                Log.e("DEBUG2", "Han canviat les dades del joc " + playerId);

                DatabaseReference playerRef = database.getReference("games/" + gameName + "/players/" + playerId);
                DatabaseReference posicioActualRef = playerRef.child("actualPosition");
                Log.e("posicioActualRef",posicioActualRef.toString());
                Player jugadorActual = playersMap.get(playerId);
                Integer actualPosition = dataSnapshot.child("players/"+playerId+"/actualPosition").getValue(Integer.class);
                Log.e("actualPosition: ",actualPosition.toString());

                jugadorActual.setActualPosition(actualPosition);

                posicioActualCasella = actualPosition;

                //mostrarCasella(gameName, actualPosition + 1); //mostrar casella actual
                movePiece(jugadorActual);                             //moure peça

            }
```

Methods:

movePiece just hide and show the pieces in the board

```
    private void movePiece(Player player){

        //logica del joc aqui
        switch (player.getColor()) {
            case "Blau":
                blauPieceList.get(player.getPosicioAnterior()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                blauPieceList.get(player.getActualPosition()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Verd":
                verdPieceList.get(player.getPosicioAnterior()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                verdPieceList.get(player.getActualPosition()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Varmell":
                varmellPieceList.get(player.getPosicioAnterior()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                varmellPieceList.get(player.getActualPosition()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Groc":
                grocPieceList.get(player.getPosicioAnterior()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                grocPieceList.get(player.getActualPosition()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Lila":
                lilaPieceList.get(player.getPosicioAnterior()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                lilaPieceList.get(player.getActualPosition()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

throw is executed in the onCreate ( in the run() ) and is who updates the data in the firebase

```
    private void tirada(String gameName) {

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        String playerId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference playerRef = database.getReference("games/"+gameName+"/players/" + playerId);
        DatabaseReference posicioAnteriorRef = playerRef.child("posicioAnterior");
        DatabaseReference posicioActualRef = playerRef.child("actualPosition");

        Player player = playersMap.get(playerId);
        int posAnterior = player.getActualPosition();
        player.setActualPosition(player.getActualPosition()+rollDice());
        player.setPosicioAnterior(posAnterior);
        posicioAnteriorRef.setValue(player.getPosicioAnterior());//to firebase
        posicioActualRef.setValue(player.getActualPosition());//to firebase


    }
```

And this is my firebase structure:

```
    "a": {
      "board": {
        "boxes": [
          {
            "description": "gggg",
            "filled": true,
            "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ocaloka-3e3f1.appspot.com/o/images%2F1563024d-fd97-4fbb-8ed6-df9bbe5e49f4.jpg?alt=media&token=5a40f91c-c5c4-4211-ad6e-38cad7ba47d5",
            "title": "I ggg"
          },
          {
            "description": "descripciocasellanumero1 casella",
            "filled": true,
            "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ocaloka-3e3f1.appspot.com/o/images%2Feb526feb-6b09-42a1-b112-a9104b707776.jpg?alt=media&token=9c651dfc-ddbb-439f-ba18-e99bd79339cf",
            "title": "chippi"
          }
        ],
        "name": "TaulellPle",
        "numFilledBoxes": 25
      },
      "currentPlayerIndex": 0,
      "name": "a",
      "players": {
        "iSQNMwneHLTeD52y7mb0hu0nYjH2": {
          "actualPosition": 0,
          "posicioAnterior": 0,
          "email": "homesexe23@gmail.com",
          "isOwner": true,
          "name": "home sexe23"
        }
      },
      "started": false
    }
  }
}
```

Could be that maybe im using .getCurrentUser() and this generate a loop somewhere?

```
    private void throw(String gameName) {

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        String playerId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference playerRef = database.getReference("games/"+gameName+"/players/" + playerId);
        DatabaseReference posicioAnteriorRef = playerRef.child("posicioAnterior");
        DatabaseReference posicioActualRef = playerRef.child("actualPosition");

        Player player = playersMap.get(playerId);
        int posAnterior = player.getActualPosition();
        player.setActualPosition(player.getActualPosition()+rollDice());
        player.setPosicioAnterior(posAnterior);
        posicioAnteriorRef.setValue(player.getPosicioAnterior());//pujar firebase
        posicioActualRef.setValue(player.getActualPosition());//pujar firebase


    }
```

Thanks!

The other methods like loadBoard and loadBoxes just paint the load the board and paint the boxes into the board using a addListenerForSingleValueEvent so i dont think is the reason of the infinite loop. If you need to see more information about the project just ask.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `addValueEventListener` you are adding a **permanent** listener, which immediately gets the current value at the path - and then gets called whenever there are updates under that path.

When your code later writes to `posicioActualRef` that seems to update data under the path that you added the listener to. So that triggers another call to your `onDataChange`, which then updates `posicioActualRef` again, which triggers an other call to `onDataChange`, etc.

---

If you only want to read the value once and then update a value under it, use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: But if I execute the method withs a addListenerForSingleValueEvent still being and infinite loop and and I also need him to listen all the time to update the position of all the players.

Comment: First off: does the explanation in my answer on why you're getting an infinite listen->write->listen->write loop make sense? And does it explain why you're getting into this situation? --- If so, and you can't use the solution I describe, you will need to find another way to break the infinite loop yourself.  The API can't help you here as this is part of your application logic. Common approach are to listen to less data, so that you don't listen to the data that you're updating, or to have a condition in your code that breaks the loop. But as said, that's application logic.

Comment: Yea the listen->write -> listen->write logic make sense but i'm not able to see why. I mean i'm executing the method throw like `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
` so I'm updating the current user values so dont alter betwen the players right?
Because if i use a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addListenerValueEvent` the same persist

Comment: So you mean the problem could be the `DatabaseReference posicioActualRef = playerRef.child("actualPosition"); ` in the `onDataChange`?